# Execute JavaScript function defined inside a class constructor, using the class's object

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, constructor

I've created a class "BFSPlayer" in Javascript with a constructor, and inside this constructor I've defined a function(which is not executed) named "myFunction".
Then I've created an object "obj" of BFSPlayer class and then I want to run that myFunction for this object.
Here's how I'm trying to do it, but it's not working:

```
class BFSPlayer {
  constructor(args){
    var player;
    function myFunction(){
        player = {
            videoId: args
        }
    }
  }
}

var obj=new BFSPlayer('video-id');
obj.constructor.myFunction();
```

Any help would be thankful to me

Comment: Function `myFunction()` is private to the constructor function. It is not a property of the constructed object and it is not a property of  the constructor function itself. It is no more available outside the constructor than the variable "player" is.

Comment: Assign it to this inside a constructor. this.myFunction = function myFunction(){...

Comment: Thanks @vbykovsky your method is working great for me :), since you have commented and not posted an answer, therefore can't accept it as an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```js
class BFSPlayer {
  player = {};

  constructor(args){
    this.player = {
      videoId: args,
    };
    
  }
  
  // I cant imageing what you wanna do here)
  //function myFunction(){
  //      player = {
  //          videoId: args
  //      }
  //  }
}

var obj = new BFSPlayer('video-id');

console.log(obj); //{ "player": { "videoId": "video-id" } }

// if you extract function from comment in class, you can use in this way
//obj.myFunction();
```